# Is it possible to play a sound from an app in background

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, ibeacon

I am working on an iOS app, that connects to an iBeacon.
I want to be able to play sounds from the phone, if external parameters match.
I have enabled "Audio, Airplay, and picture in picture." in Background Modes.

Right now I have the issue, that it can only play sounds from the app, while:

- App is in foreground.
- Screen is locked, and phone is not silent.

I would like it to also be able to play sounds, while:

- Locked screen and phone is silent.
- Background (when app is started by iBeacon).

Is there any way to achieve this?

The function I use to play sound is:

```
private var avPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

// MARK: - Play Sound
internal func playSound(forResource resource: String, ofType type: String) {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource, ofType: type)  else {
        print("Test: Failed getting path for \(resource)")
        return
    }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    
    // Handle playing in background
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(.playback, options: [.duckOthers])
        try session.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("Test: Failed setting category on session \(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        avPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    } catch let error {
        print("Test: Failed adding url to AVAudioPlayer \(error)")
    }
    
    avPlayer?.play()
}
```

And called like:

```
        playSound(forResource: "SoundToPlay", ofType: "wav")
```

Comment: you need to enable background audio: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio

Comment: @KirilS. Audio, Airplay, and picture in picture. Is enabled in Background Modes.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your app to listen for beacon region notifications then you can trigger sounds to play when you enter or leave a region, even if the phone is locked and/or your app was not running. I'm not sure if those would play if the user has the phone muted (I suspect not)